# Is there a maximum angle for total internal reflection (TIR) above which TIR won't happen?

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction

I came across such a concept when I learnt about fibre optic cables and T.I.R. There was this question:

> Light guidance in an optical fibre can be understood by considering a structure comprising of thin solid glass cylinder of refractive index $n_1$ surrounded by a medium of lower refractive index $n_2$.
>
> The light guidance in the structure takes place due to successive total internal reflections at the interface of the media $n_1$ and $n_2$ as shown in the figure. All rays with the angle of incidence $i$ less than a particular value $i_m$ are confined in the medium of refractive index $n_1$. The numerical aperture (NA) of the structure is defined as $\sin(i_m)$.

It was to find the combined N.A. of two structures.

Comment: You could have answered this question by reading the Wikipedia article on [Total Internal Reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_internal_reflection#Critical_angle).

Comment: Thanks. I will check

Answer (score 1):

The confusion arises from the definition of the angle of incidence $i$. The text you quote comes from a JEE question and the associated diagram is:

[image: Fibre optic]

The angle $i$ is the angle the incident light makes to the axis of the optic fibre not the angle to the normal at the interface between the core and the cladding. That is, when we are calculating whether total internal reflection occurs in the fibre we need to consider the angle $90 - i$.